# Product metric, continuity of functions and minimum

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose there are $n$ metric spaces $(X_i,d_i)$, and $X$ being the product space with the product metric $\rho$.

In proving that the projection function $\pi_i(x_1,...,x_n) = x_i$ is continuous, the proof follows something like this (not rigorous since it's only serving to motivate the question):

---

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. Then we get the existence of $\delta := \varepsilon *2^{-i}$ such that

$\rho(x,y)$ = $\sum_{j=1}^{n} 2^{-j} min(1, d_j(x_j,y_j))$ < $\delta$

Implies that, for a specific $i$,

$2^{-i}d_i(x_i,y_i) \leq \sum_{j=1}^{n} 2^{-j} min\{1, d_j(x_j,y_j)\} < \delta$ (1)

So $d_i(x_i,y_i) < \varepsilon$ and the function is continuous.

---

In this proof, it actually follows that we can, without lose of generality, consider $min\{1,d_i(x_i,y_i)\}$ as $d_i(x_i,y_i)$, in (1). I would like to know why that is the case.

Thanks

Comment: That is because d and min{ 1,d } are equivalent metrics, that is generate the same topology.  The proposition can be proved in general without the use of any metrics by considering the inverse image of an open set by a projection.

Comment: Could you provide a hint for proving this with inverse image of an open set?

Answer (score 1):

Let p = $\pi_i:X_1×..×X_n$ -> $X_i, (x_1,.. x_n)$ -> $x_i.$
To show p is continuous, let U be any open subset of $X_i$
and show $p^{-1}(U) is open.  This will also show
projections of infinite products are continuous.

In fact without much ado the projections can be shown to be open.

Comment: Thanks. How do I deal with the fact that many vectors in X lead to a projection of $x_i$? So the pre-image has many possible points.

Comment: What vectors?  Topological spaces have points, they do not have vectors.   The preimage of a set A by a function f is { x : f(X) in A }.  It is uniquely determined and will be empty, a singleton, finite or infinite.